# jQuery - add a set width to div?

Tags: jquery

I need to add a set number of pixels to a `div` with jQuery.

Is there an easy command for this or will I need to write some code that first finds the width of the element and then adds the set amount?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Or a third alternative,

```
$("#mydiv").css("width", "+=10");
```

Comment: I tried something like this but it doesn't worked...
`$("#myDiv").load(function(){  //my code went here     })`

Answer (score 5):

You'll need to write the code yourself. However, doing what you want is trivial:

```
$('#mydiv').width($('#mydiv').width() + 10);
```

Or another way, which will work for a whole set of elements:

```
$('.mydiv').width(function(index, value) {
    return value + 10;
});
```