# Change div's width by a value in JS

Tags: javascript, html, width

How to change `div`'s width by a certain value, like this:

```
someDiv.style.width += "100px";
```

It works when I want to **set** a value (i.e. `width = "100px"`) but the problem is with `+=` operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work for a vanilla javascript solution (since you didn't mention jquery):

```
var someDiv = document.getElementById("someDiv");
var w = 0;
if (typeof someDiv.clip !== "undefined") {
    w = someDiv.clip.width;
} else {
    if (someDiv.style.pixelWidth) {
        w = someDiv.style.pixelWidth;
    } else {
        w = someDiv.offsetWidth;
    }
}
someDiv.style.width = (w + 100) + "px";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="test" style="height:100px"></div>

var elem=document.getElementById("test");
height=parseInt(elem.style.height);
height+=100;
height+="px"
console.log(height);
```

Try the following 
http://jsfiddle.net/CME3Y/

Comment: `parseInt(elem.style.height)` returns `NaN`

Comment: oh? I tried the jsfiddle and got 200px as the answer. have you a clue, why it evaluates in your case to that?

Comment: maybe because he doesn't have a set css value for it in the first place

Comment: I'm calling my function in body's onload and not setting div's width explicitly anywhere - could that be the problem?

Comment: Maybe. Perhaps you try the example I provided ;)

Answer (score 0):

That is because Javascript can't understand what "100px" + "100px" means, since those are string values.

I would do it like this using jQuery:

```
$(someDiv).width($(someDiv).width() + 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var currentwidth= $('#div').width();
$('#div').width(currentwidth +100);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dolours/CME3Y/1/

Also you can use this https://stackoverflow.com/a/6179629/1479798